# Convert immutable array from string to number

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a `Vanilla JS` array, containing numbers as `strings`.

```
const stringArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
```

If I want to convert all the numbers in the array to `intger` I simply do

```
const integerArray = stringArray.map(Number);
```

Now, I have an `Immutable JS List`

```
const immutableListStrings = Immutable.List(stringArray);
```

Using

```
immutableListStrings.map(Number);
```

does not convert the `strings` to `integer`. Why is that?

Comment: I have no knowledge about immutable.js, but in vanilla JS `Array.prototype.map` does not change the array in place.

Comment: Just like with standard map, Immutable's `.map` returns a new `List` (https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/map). In fact, the whole point of the library is to create/use immutable data structures so operations usually return a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` in general literally maps through your list values and allows you to transform them before putting them into a **new** list.

`map` does not transform your current list.

You simply need to create a new variable (i.e.: immutableNumbers)

```js
const stringArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
const immutableListStrings = Immutable.List(stringArray);
const immutableNumbers = immutableListStrings.map(Number);

console.log(immutableNumbers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```